# Why should there is a $c\in [0,1]$: $f(c)=f(c+1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

[Problem of continuous real valued function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651671/problem-of-continuous-real-valued-function)

I don't understand  Jim's comment on (b). He took $g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. Why should there is a $c\in [0,1]$: $f(c)=f(c+1)$.

I can't apply mean value theorem here directly. Since given function need not be differentiable. I am not able to find a condition of IVT too.

Regarding the answer to (c)I understood.

Comment: It's the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Just apply IVT to $g$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: $g(0)=f(1)-f(0)$ and $g(1)=f(2)-f(1)$. But we don't know the value of $f(1)$

Comment: We know $f(2)=f(0)$ though.

Comment: You know $f(2)=f(0)$ though.

Answer (score 2):

$g(0) = f(1)-f(0)$ while $g(1)=f(2)-f(1) = f(0)-f(1)=-g(0)$.

So if $g(0)$ is positive, $g(1)$ is negative and vice versa (or both are $0$ already).

The **intermediate** value theorem (IVT) implies that a continuous $g$ must have a point where it assumes $0$ inbetween those points.